Assign date order (mm/dd/yyyy) to a date time character in R
I have loaded datalogger csv files. Here I include a fragment. The date_time column is ordered as month/day/year and hour:min:sec:
date_time<-c("6/5/22 10:22:01 AM", "6/5/22 10:23:01 AM", "6/5/22 10:24:01 AM", "6/5/22 10:25:01 AM", "6/5/22 10:26:01 AM", "6/5/22 10:27:01 AM",
 "6/5/22 10:28:01 AM", "6/5/22 10:29:01 AM", "6/5/22 10:30:01 AM", "6/5/22 10:31:01 AM", "6/5/22 10:32:01 AM", "6/5/22 10:33:01 AM")
temp<-c(21.296, 22.047, 22.798, 22.422, 22.172, 22.673, 22.360, 22.110, 21.922, 21.797, 21.672, 21.609)

df<-data.frame(date_time,temp)
df

         date_time   temp
1  6/5/22 10:22:01 AM 21.296
2  6/5/22 10:23:01 AM 22.047
3  6/5/22 10:24:01 AM 22.798
4  6/5/22 10:25:01 AM 22.422
5  6/5/22 10:26:01 AM 22.172
6  6/5/22 10:27:01 AM 22.673
7  6/5/22 10:28:01 AM 22.360
8  6/5/22 10:29:01 AM 22.110
9  6/5/22 10:30:01 AM 21.922
10 6/5/22 10:31:01 AM 21.797
11 6/5/22 10:32:01 AM 21.672
12 6/5/22 10:33:01 AM 21.609

The date_time column appears as a character,
str(df)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date_time: chr  "6/5/22 10:22:01 AM" "6/5/22 10:23:01 AM" "6/5/22 10:24:01 AM" "6/5/22 10:25:01 AM" ...
 $ temp     : num  21.3 22 22.8 22.4 22.2 ...

but I want it to be a posixct variable, so I applied the as.POSIXct function:
df$date_time<-as.POSIXct(df$date_time)


 df
             date_time   temp
1  0006-05-22 10:22:01 21.296
2  0006-05-22 10:23:01 22.047
3  0006-05-22 10:24:01 22.798
4  0006-05-22 10:25:01 22.422
5  0006-05-22 10:26:01 22.172
6  0006-05-22 10:27:01 22.673
7  0006-05-22 10:28:01 22.360
8  0006-05-22 10:29:01 22.110
9  0006-05-22 10:30:01 21.922
10 0006-05-22 10:31:01 21.797
11 0006-05-22 10:32:01 21.672
12 0006-05-22 10:33:01 21.609

However, it puts the days as years and vice-versa.
By specifying the format, it does not work:
df$date_time<-as.POSIXct(df$date_time,format="%dd-%mm-%YYYY %H:%M:%S")
df

             date_time   temp
1  0006-05-22 10:22:01 21.296
2  0006-05-22 10:23:01 22.047
3  0006-05-22 10:24:01 22.798
4  0006-05-22 10:25:01 22.422
5  0006-05-22 10:26:01 22.172
6  0006-05-22 10:27:01 22.673
7  0006-05-22 10:28:01 22.360
8  0006-05-22 10:29:01 22.110
9  0006-05-22 10:30:01 21.922
10 0006-05-22 10:31:01 21.797
11 0006-05-22 10:32:01 21.672
12 0006-05-22 10:33:01 21.609

How can assign correctly the order of date (mm/dd/yyyy)? Any advice would be helpful
Thanks in advance!

Perfect, @JohanRosa, thanks. The only thing I had to change was the order of the date :idf$date_time<-lubridate::mdy_hms(df$date_time)

A good starting point when encontering unexpected behaviour is the documentation, c.f. ?as.POSIXct. Here you can see from which format definitions the function tries to guess if format is not specified. If you are interested in learning more about these abbreviations, see also ?strptime.

Two options:
1- while using as.POSIXct() you didn't use the correct format
as.POSIXct(df$date_time, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
2- Use the lubridate package, it has many useful fuctions to handle date time objects
ubridate::mdy_hms(df$date_time)

Perfect, @JohanRosa, thanks. The only thing I had to change was the order of the date :
df$date_time<-lubridate::mdy_hms(df$date_time)

Great, I wasn't sure if you had "dmy" or "mdy", I did it based on the format you posted. I'll change it in the andwer :)
